# What to do when a flag still has active status?

Tags: support

Within the last few hours or so, I noticed a "new" person in the chat room and made a cryptic "Oh dear" comment in chat.

Based on my two-bit forensic ability, I suspected that this person was up to no good.

I checked the person's profile and found that the person had posted one upvoted answer. I looked at that answer and found something about it that I thought merited flagging and so I flagged it with a brief reason.

Eight hours later, I find that the flag still has "active" status but that the user's profile is a page that can't be found.

Unless I'm totally incompetent, I now can't find the answer I flagged *and even the question that provoked it*.

My questions are:

- What happens to the flag I raised? Won't I get credit for a "helpful" flag?
- Why did the question disappear as well, assuming it has disappeared?

BTW, if it's just a matter of the mods not having yet got around to it, that's perfectly fine given that most of us are voluntarily volunteering our time here in whatever way we can.

Comment: If you look in your flag history it will have a link to the answer so you can tell if it has been deleted or not (you don't seem to be sure).

Comment: Thanks! I was so concerned about the active status that I overlooked that. The question has been removed "for reasons of moderation". But the flag is still active. Oh, well.

Comment: I moderator will probably get to it in the next day or two. Sometimes there are a lot of flags to be handled :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the only correct answers is: wait.

Comment: I will concoct a related question after some time.

Comment: Waited and the flag was accepted.